# "Eloquent Javascript" recursion exercise

Tags: javascript

The objective is not to use any of build in functions related to math to determine "isEven", ***but what is isEven(-n) suppose to do***, and for those pondering what (n-2) does is that it subtracts a variable to a point of arriving to 1 or 0 (I don't belief that the book explains what the exercise is, so just looked at the answer).

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return true;
  else if (n == 1)
    return false;
  else if (n < 0)
    return isEven(-n);
  else
    return isEven(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This sounds like homework.

Comment: `but what is isEven(-n) suppose to do` tell me, what's the negative of a negative value?

Comment: This question is from the Eloquent JavaScript book. The exercise is to find even numbers using a recursive function rather than using the modulus operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that just turns any negative number into a positive number, so for instance:

`-10`, `10`, `8`, `6`, `4`, `2`,`0` => `even`

Comment: How do you figure that? It doesn't even return a number. It checks if a number is even.

Comment: This is a recursive function that continues to call itself.  It checks for 0 or 1, and otherwise it inverts negative numbers or subtracts 2, eventually returning true or false.  The specific line he asked about, "what is isEven(-n) suppose to do" turns negatives into positives and continues chaining itself.